# Best practice for redesigning a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

Basically need to use SharePoint (because we promote MS yay!) as a content management system for an internet facing site.

How do I get rid of the default SharePoint look and feel and make it look like however I want it to?

I know the process involves creating a new masterpage with SharePoint Designer.  However I prefer to code webpages rather than use a visual editor.  Is this possible? Do I need knowledge of .NET?

Just check out ferrari.com for a very well made redesign of a SharePoint site.

Comment: SharePoint can almost certainly do what you need it to, but if you don't have pretty extensive CMS needs it may be overkill. Your platform should be chosen based on requirements, not management's desire to appease Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

Heather Solomon's [Branding SharePoint series](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/brandsppart1.aspx) would be a good place to start. There's a lot you can do just with CSS, JS and HTML, but the most complete solutions (like Ferrari) require some pretty extensive customization with .NET and other SharePoint development techniques (features and delegate controls, in particular).

Your branding effort will be a lot easier if you only need to heavily brand the public-facing "publishing pages", from which you can remove most of the SharePoint-specific elements that make branding difficult.

Also, SharePoint Designer has a source view if you don't like the visual editor.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to make it look like however you want it to (as you've seen from the Ferrari site). However to create that sort of site takes a **lot of work**.

Microsoft recommend the use of SharePoint Designer for 'designing' pages and layouts. However changing their behaviour almost always needs Visual Studio and development in .NET. You can largely avoid SharePoint Designer (which may worth considering as it can be a PITA) with an open source tool such as [SPVisualDev](http://www.codeplex.com/SPVisualDev). Use this with [WSPBuilder](http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder) for packaging your solutions (and avoid VSeWSS where possible).

Considering it sounds like you're just getting started, be aware this is a big topic with a reasonable learning curve. **Read a good book** on the topic such as [Professional SharePoint 2007 Web Content Management Development: Building Publishing Sites with Office SharePoint Server 2007](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470224754) by Andrew Connell. It takes you through most things you will encounter from the ground up.

Comment: As much of a pain SPD can be, there are still some things it can do (particularly with page layouts) that are too handy not to use for prototyping and design work. Just be sure to capture SPD artifacts into source control, packaged and deployed into production with WSPs.

Comment: @dahlbyk Absolutely - source control can be easily missed. SPVisualDev helps here in assisting to create features to deploy page layouts, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working my way through [Real World Branding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354191.aspx) by Andrew Connell at the moment. It seems like a good demonstration, with code.

Plus the Heather Solomon articles as suggested by dahlbyk are always informative.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the theme, or creating a custom theme for the site, can go a long way towards making SharePoint look a lot better.  It's also a lot less intensive then changing the master pages.

[How to create a theme](http://beyondsharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-custom-theme-for-sharepoint.html)

[How to deploy a theme](http://alonsorobles.com/2008/06/26/packaging-branding-and-themes-for-deployment-in-sharepoint-environments/)

[Example customization you can do with just CSS](http://www.rightpointconsulting.com/community/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2009/07/05/how-it-works-customizing-sharepoint-search-bar-via-css.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Does the EULA allow you to disguise the fact that it's MS software?

Remember, you didn't *buy* the software, you're just paying for the privilege of using it.

Comment: @pavium That's not relevant, SharePoint is designed to be re-themed for public facing web sites.

Comment: Hi pavium.  My intention is not to hide that fact that it is using MS software but to make the theme match the company brand.

Comment: Well, yes of course the idea was to theme the software in line with your company brand, but I'm frankly gobsmacked that MS encourages this. My limited experience of Sharepoint gave no hint of it.

Comment: I'm Kevin and I work on SharePoint. We definitely allow and encourage people to customize their sites to meet their needs, branding and otherwise.

Comment: I applaud that, but as a mere user of SharePoint I wasn't aware of any possible customisation. I suppose the MIS person where I work just doesn't have the time to customise the site.